# Raspberry Pi Camera reboots when I tap on touchscreen

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, camera

I am trying myself at the Raspberry Pi Camera project as presented by Hi, [Phil Burgess](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-wifi-raspberry-pi-touch-cam).

For whatever reason, my pi is rebooting every time I click on the touchscreen to take a picture. When I tap on the touchscreen, it shows the little flower for a while then the whole pi reboots. Any reason why?

Anybody ever experienced that? What's a good solution? Thanks!

Comment: The battery pack comes to mind, what're you using? Rebooting often means not enough current.

Comment: Been a while but... I was using one of those Powerbank portable batteries that one can use to recharge their phones. I think you are right about it being a current issue. I eventually deleted everything to start over. I got rid of some custom functions that the Pi was having to process at the same time (requesting more current) as the screen tap and that did it. Less current was being demanded and all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the number of functions that were drawing more current and that solved the issue. Current seems to have been the issue.